# Embed customized map into website using Google Map api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to embed a custom (shared) google map i've created with specific markers into my website using the Google map api and javascript. The public link to the map: https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=zsBifQnz-5Kg.kzYonBq-f6oo&usp=sharing

I know that it is possible with iframe. But I need to add some links later on with js to the markers as well.

If its not possible, is there any way to get all the geo location data lat, and long from my custom map to dinamycally create my map?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the google-maps javascript API and directly use the KMZ or KML that you create off your custom map. Just go to the options in your custom map and click "Download KML". If you plan to continue to make changes to your map, I would suggest the network KMZ file. The maps-api has a library to use this KMZ directly only a map.